# Backshifting of future subordinate

Tags: future, subordinate-clauses, indirect-speech

*I will help you when you grow up*

Which sentences are correct? (I think the 1. is the correct one in a grammatical sense. The second may not be the best version, yet I have seen/heard this construction many times already.)

**1. She said that she would help him when he grew up**

**2. She said that she would help him when he grows up**

By the way is it common to report a speech using the present perfect? *She has said that vs She said that*

Comment: They're both fine. #1 would normally be used if at time of speaking he's *already* grown up, and #2 would be more appropriate if he's still a child.

Answer (score 1):

#1 is colloquially problematic. Or should I have written *problematically colloquial*.

It is better and more comprehensible to deploy a completed participle:

> She said that she would help him when he's grown up

Whereas, #2 provides the fragrant hint of a non-finite. Not exactly, but somewhat non-finite.

- I will be a happy wife when he finally **eats** durians.
- We will be exhilarated when he **discovers** a molecular structure to contain those huge esters from decomposing pungently at temperatures above 45 fahrenheit.
- Her dad will see the light at the end of his financial tunnel when she **graduates** from engineering school.
- His mom would be very much more relaxed when a **grows up** to be an adult.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So in this case when reporting a future subordinate (with a present tense) we don't back-shift to the simple past? Is it because the present has precisely a future sense? In a previous question where I wanted to report this: _Can you go outside today? - I don't know yet, I need my parents' approval first_, I've been told it should be _If James asked his friend if she could go outside, she would tell him she **needed** her parents' approval first._

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonfinite_verb

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/289903/simple-present-they-build-a-house-next-to-mine-why-is-it-wrong/289987#289987

Comment: So the answer is that in my previous example (_approval before going out_, let's call it 3.) we use a simple past as usual whereas in 1. it is best to use a present perfect because in 1 "grow up" is a non-finite event? If so, can we say that in all the future subordinates the verb Y is non-finite? **I will X when Y happens**

Comment: Just realised addendum needed: His mom would be very much more relaxed when **he** grows up to be an adult

Comment: It is not the event that is non-finite, but the temporally-neutral language used. Non-finite verbs and verb-derivatives are born out of efficiency (laziness is the root of efficiency) to be able to apply the same modular phrase to past, present, future, indefinite, propositional or delusional events.